# Python Parsing csv file containing ip and ports

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, network-programming

I'm working on small project that parse csv file

so csv file I'm working on should contain IPs with opened ports separated with commas

192.168.10.45,80,443,20,21,8080

192.168.10.49,22,80,21

So, I am trying to read this file then write an output file for each port that contain IP addresses for ip with that port opned. e.g.
22.txt should contain

192.168.10.45
192.168.10.49

Any idea how I could do that or a good reference. I am still noob in python3

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print((row)[1])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the file containing lists of ip addresses and ports only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not use the csv lib because your csv has no header and has a variable number of open ports. It is easier and less code / deps. this way.

**VERSION 1 without csv package**

```
import os, sys
from collections import defaultdict

def main(csv):

    # use defaultdict so there is no need to initialize
    # use set to remove duplicate entries
    port_ip_map = defaultdict(set)

    # open with, handles errors open closing file handles etc.
    with open(csv, 'r') as f:
        # read lines
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            # ip must always be the first entry
            # port lists can have a variable length
            ip, *ports = line.split(',')
            for port in ports:
                # save ips by port
                port = int(port.strip())
                port_ip_map[port].add(ip)



    for port, ips in port_ip_map.items():
        line = ' '.join(ips)
        with open('{}.txt'.format(port), 'w') as f:
            f.write(line)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main(sys.argv[1])  # pass csv file by cli
    main('./test1.csv')
```

**VERSION 2 with csv package**

```
import os, sys, csv
from collections import defaultdict

def main(csv_path):

    # use defaultdict so there is no need to initialize
    # use set to remove duplicate entries
    port_ip_map = defaultdict(set)

    # open with, handles errors open closing file handles etc.
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as f:
        # read lines
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:

            # ip must always be the first entry
            # port lists can have a variable length
            ip, *ports = row
            for port in ports:
                # save ips by port
                port = int(port.strip())
                port_ip_map[port].add(ip)



    for port, ips in port_ip_map.items():
        line = ' '.join(ips)
        with open('{}.txt'.format(port), 'w') as f:
            f.write(line)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main(sys.argv[1])  # pass csv file by cli
    main('./test1.csv')
```

sample input: test1.csv

```
192.168.10.49,22,80,21
192.168.10.45,80,443,20,21,8080
```

sample output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {22: {'192.168.10.49'}, 80: {'192.168.10.45', '192.168.10.49'}, 21: {'192.168.10.45', '192.168.10.49'}, 443: {'192.168.10.45'}, 20: {'192.168.10.45'}, 8080: {'192.168.10.45'}})
```

Comment: you can do, but there is no need to, forgot to add writing the port.txt files. add it in a moment

Comment: Yes there is. Now you are rolling your own csv split instead.

Comment: added version using csv package. still think it is overkill but not my position to decide ;)

Comment: Thanks @mumbala for your help. Second version does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the port you are looking for is the second argument to the script you could do:

```
import csv
import sys

infile = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]

with open(infile, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if port in row[1:]:
            print('{}:{}'.format(row[0], port))
```

Here, for each row in your file, the line `if port in row[1:]` will look for the port in each of the elements of the list. I assume that is what you want?

Note, that I have modified the `print` line slightly to print also the port.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a Python Dictionary, or dict. There is also an OrderedDict from the collections library.

For example:

```
    import collections

    ips_ordered_by_port = collections.OrderedDict()
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row_parts = row.split(',')
        ip = row_parts[0]
        for row_part_idx in range(1, len(row_parts)):
            port = row_parts[row_part_idx]
            ip_ordered_by_port = ips_ordered_by_port.get(port)
            if ip_ordered_by_port is None:
                ips_ordered_by_port[port] = ip
            else:
                ip_ordered_by_port.update(ip)
```

Now you will have a dict ordered by port (the key) and for each key the items (values) will be the ip address. To iterate through each key, create a file for that key and write all the IP address I leave to you.

Of course the above code could be refactored out into several functions for better readability and testability.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ozOil for your help. Will try get better in python and get the job done myself.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the ipaddress module, and put it back into another csv.  Very useful when working with firewall or load balancer configs.  Putting it back into a csv file lets you reformat it on your desktop to excel, then create tables off of port numbers.

```
import ipaddress
import csv

list1 = []
list2 = []

with open(file, "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="'", dialect="excel")
    for i in csvreader:
        try:
            if ipaddress.IPv4Address(i[1]).version == 4:
                list1.append(i[1])
            elif int(i[2]) == True:
                list2.append(i[2])          
            except ipaddress.AddressValueError:
                pass
            except IndexError:
                pass

rows = zip(list1, list2)

with open(file + "_final.csv", "w") as finalcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(finalcsv, dialect="excel")
    for i in rows:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Count Duplicate IP's in a CSV Column. example (192.168.0.1 3 times)

192.168.0.1
198.168.1.101
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1

Comment: Are you asking?